# How to convert flac inside mkv ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska, flac, pcm

Guys! I was wanting to know if anyone can tell me how to losslessly convert FLAC audio to LPCM without any quality loss at all?

This is info from of the mkv. Stream #0:0: Video,  Stream #0:1: Audio: flac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16,  Stream #0:2: Subtitle: ass

ffmpeg -i A.mkv -map 0 -c:v copy -c:a ??? -ar 48000 -ac 2 -c:s copy B.mkv

What the correct command to convert flac 16 bit to pcm 16 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0 -c copy -c:a pcm_s16le output.mkv
```

- `-map 0` includes all streams. See [FFmpeg Wiki: Map](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map) and [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection).
- `-c copy` [stream copies](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) everything (except audio due to the next option).
- `-c:a pcm_s16le` encodes all audio with the encoder named pcm_s16le.

Comment: Thank you for the correct ffmpeg format.